# Populating Spring @Value during Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-annotations

I'm trying to write a Unit Test for a simple bean that's used in my program to validate forms. The bean is annotated with `@Component` and has a class variable that is initialized using

```
@Value("${this.property.value}") private String thisProperty;
```

I would like to write unit tests for the validation methods inside this class, however, if possible I would like to do so without utilizing the properties file. My reasoning behind this, is that if the value I'm pulling from the properties file changes, I would like that to not affect my test case. My test case is testing the code that validates the value, not the value itself.

Is there a way to use Java code inside my test class to initialize a Java class and populate the Spring @Value property inside that class then use that to test with?

I did find this [How To](https://gist.github.com/danlangford/3418696) that seems to be close, but still uses a properties file. I would rather it all be Java code.

Comment: I have described a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59736272/4748886) for similar problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

If possible I would try to write those test without Spring Context. If you create this class in your test without spring, then you have full control over its fields.

To set the `@value` field you can use Springs [`ReflectionTestUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) - it has a method [`setField`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) to set private fields.

@see [JavaDoc: ReflectionTestUtils.setField(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: Or even without Spring dependencies at all by changing the field to default access (package protected) to make it simply accessible to the test.

Comment: Example : `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classUnderTest, "field", "value");`

Comment: You may want to make these fields set by the constructor and then move the `@Value` annotation to the constructor parameter.  This makes the test code much simpler when writing the code manually, and Spring Boot doesn't care.

Comment: This is the best answer to just quickly change one property for a single testcase.

Comment: ReflectionTestUtils works with Java 17 or above? Since reflection no longer gives warning, it gives error

Comment: Would not cut it, if you want to test also whether your datatype will be mapped correctly with @Value. double for example..

Answer (score 263):

Since Spring 4.1 you could set up property values just in code by using `org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource` annotation on Unit Tests class level. You could use this approach even for injecting properties into dependent bean instances

For example

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = FooTest.Config.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "some.bar.value=testValue",
})
public class FooTest {

  @Value("${some.bar.value}")
  String bar;

  @Test
  public void testValueSetup() {
    assertEquals("testValue", bar);
  }


  @Configuration
  static class Config {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesResolver() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

  }

}
```

**Note:** It's necessary to have instance of `org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in Spring context

**Edit 24-08-2017:** If you are using SpringBoot 1.4.0 and later you could initialize tests with [`@SpringBootTest`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) and [`@SpringBootConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html) annotations. More info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-configfileapplicationcontextinitializer-test-utility)

In case of SpringBoot we have following code

```
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBootConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "some.bar.value=testValue",
})
public class FooTest {

  @Value("${some.bar.value}")
  String bar;

  @Test
  public void testValueSetup() {
    assertEquals("testValue", bar);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, finally someone answered how to override Value and not how to set a field. I derive values from the string field in PostConstruct and so I need the string value to be set by Spring, not after construction.

Comment: @Value("$aaaa")  - can you use this inside class Config itself?

Comment: I'm not sure because Config is static class. But please feel free to check

Comment: How can I use @Value annotation in Mockito Test class?

Comment: I'm writing an integration test for a service which doesn't refer any code which fetch values from property file but my application has configuration class which is fetching value from property file. So when I'm running test it is giving error of unresolve placeholder , say  "${spring.redis.port}"

Comment: Note that using `TestPropertySource` annotation in different test classes will result in the creation of a new Spring context for each class.
A nice article on multiple spring-context and how to avoid it: https://medium.com/@mykola.gurov/integration-tests-v-spring-context-when-less-is-more-2e454572c3a8

Comment: The original question refers to an isolated unit test, while this solution is dependent on a Spring context.

Comment: @fyrkov actually not
_Is there a way to use Java code inside my test class to initialize a Java class and populate the Spring @Value property inside that class then use that to test with?_
Where `Spring Value` is filled by the Spring Engine. In this case, my comment gives a correct answer.

Comment: You can also use an application.properties with your unit test properties as such: `@TestPropertySource("/application.properties")`

Answer (score 181):

**Don't abuse private fields get/set by reflection**

Using reflection as that is done in several answers here is something that we could avoid.
It brings a small value here while it presents multiple drawbacks :

- we detect reflection issues only at runtime (ex: fields not existing any longer)
- We want  encapsulation but not a opaque class that hides dependencies that should be visible and make the class more opaque and less testable.
- it encourages bad design.  Today you declare a `@Value String field`. Tomorrow you can declare `5` or `10` of them in that class and you may not even be straight aware that you decrease the design of the class. With a more visible approach to set these fields (such as constructor) , you will think twice before adding all these fields and you will probably encapsulate them into another class and use `@ConfigurationProperties`.

**Make your class testable both unitary and in integration**

To be able to write both plain unit tests (that is without a running spring container) and integration tests for your Spring component class, you have to make this class usable with or without Spring.
Running a container in an unit test when it is not required is a bad practice that slows down local builds : you don't want that.
I added this answer because no answer here seems to show this distinction and so they rely on a running container systematically.

So I think that you should move this property defined as an internal of the class :

```
@Component
public class Foo{   
    @Value("${property.value}") private String property;
    //...
}
```

into a constructor parameter that will be injected by Spring :

```
@Component
public class Foo{   
    private String property;
     
    public Foo(@Value("${property.value}") String property){
       this.property = property;
    }

    //...         
}
```

**Unit test example**

You can instantiate `Foo` without Spring and inject any value for `property` thanks to the constructor  :

```
public class FooTest{

   Foo foo = new Foo("dummyValue");

   @Test
   public void doThat(){
      ...
   }
}
```

**Integration test example**

You can injecting the property in the context with  Spring Boot in this simple way thanks to the `properties` attribute of `@SpringBootTest`   :

```
@SpringBootTest(properties="property.value=dummyValue")
public class FooTest{
    
   @Autowired
   Foo foo;
     
   @Test
   public void doThat(){
       ...
   }    
}
```

You could use as alternative  `@TestPropertySource` but it adds an additional annotation :

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties="property.value=dummyValue")
public class FooTest{ ...}
```

With Spring (without Spring Boot), it should be a little more complicated but as I didn't use Spring without Spring Boot for a long time, I don't prefer say a stupid thing.

As a side note: if you have many `@Value` fields to set, extracting them into a class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` is more relevant because we don't want a constructor with too many arguments.

Comment: Great answer. Best practice here is also for constructor-initialized fields to be `final`, i.e `private String final property`

Comment: It's nice that somebody highlighted that. To make it working with Spring only, it is necessary to add the class under test in @ContextConfiguration.

Comment: And if I have 10 fields with `@Value` you propose to create a constructor with 10 parameters?

Comment: @ACV never. Please read the last sentence of my answer. And the configuration properties class could have setters if many fields to set. That  is less annoying for a class that is only designed to be a  properties holder.

Comment: I think this answer provides the real solution to the problem.

Answer (score 59):

If you want, you can still run your tests within Spring Context and set the required properties inside Spring configuration class. If you use JUnit, use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and define dedicated configuration class for your tests like that:

The class under test:

```
@Component
public SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    private SomeDependency someDependency;

    @Value("${someProperty}")
    private String someProperty;
}
```

The test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeClassTestsConfig.class)
public class SomeClassTests {

    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Autowired
    private SomeDependency someDependency;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
       Mockito.reset(someDependency);

    @Test
    public void someTest() { ... }
}
```

And the configuration class for this test:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClassTestsConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() throws Exception {
        final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("someProperty", "testValue");

        pspc.setProperties(properties);
        return pspc;
    }
    @Bean
    public SomeClass getSomeClass() {
        return new SomeClass();
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeDependency getSomeDependency() {
        // Mockito used here for mocking dependency
        return Mockito.mock(SomeDependency.class);
    }
}
```

Having that said, I wouldn't recommend this approach, I just added it here for reference. In my opinion much better way is to use Mockito runner. In that case you don't run tests inside Spring at all, which is much more clear and simpler.

Comment: I agree that most logic should be tested with Mockito. I wish there was a better way of testing presence and correctness of annotations than running tests through Spring.

Answer (score 33):

This seems to work, although still a bit verbose (I'd like something shorter still):

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    System.setProperty("some.property", "<value>");
}

// Optionally:
@AfterClass
public static void afterClass() {
    System.clearProperty("some.property");
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is cleaner as it is Spring agnostic, it works well for different scenarios, like when you have to use custom test runners and cannot just add the `@TestProperty` annotation.

Comment: This only works for the Spring integration test approach. Some answers and comments in here are leaning toward a Mockito approach, for which this certainly doesn't work (since there's nothing in Mockito that will populate the `@Value`s, regardless of whether the corresponding property is set or not.

Answer (score 10):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)    // @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

May that could help. The key is ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer get all props datas

Comment: Yes! Amazing! Exactly what I needed and crazy fast! (Well... at least for a spring-boot related test 

This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Its quite old question, and I'm not sure if it was an option at that time, but this is the reason why I always prefer DependencyInjection by the constructor than by the value.

I can imagine that your class might look like this:

```
class ExampleClass{

   @Autowired
   private Dog dog;

   @Value("${this.property.value}") 
   private String thisProperty;

   ...other stuff...
}
```

You can change it to:

```
class ExampleClass{

   private Dog dog;
   private String thisProperty;

   //optionally @Autowire
   public ExampleClass(final Dog dog, @Value("${this.property.value}") final String thisProperty){
      this.dog = dog;
      this.thisProperty = thisProperty;
   }

   ...other stuff...
}
```

With this implementation, the spring will know what to inject automatically, but for unit testing, you can do whatever you need. For example Autowire every dependency wth spring, and inject them manually via constructor to create "ExampleClass" instance, or use only spring with test property file, or do not use spring at all and create all object yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Adding PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in configuration is working for me.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.DERBY);
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.test.model" });
        // Use hibernate
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
         transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
              entityManagerFactory().getObject()
         );

         return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propConfig() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        placeholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application_test.properties"));
        return placeholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

And in test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public class DataServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private DataService dataService;

    @Autowired
    private DataRepository dataRepository;

    @Value("${Api.url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Test
    public void testUpdateData() {
        List<Data> datas = (List<Data>) dataRepository.findAll();
        assertTrue(datas.isEmpty());
        dataService.updateDatas();
        datas = (List<Data>) dataRepository.findAll();
        assertFalse(datas.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In springboot 2.4.1 im just added annotation `@SpringBootTest` in my test, and obviously, setted `spring.profiles.active = test` in my `src/test/resources/application.yml`

Im using `@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})` and `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RabbitMQ.class, GenericMapToObject.class, ModelMapper.class, StringUtils.class})` for external confs

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code and it worked for me:

```
@InjectMocks
private ClassNotify classNotify;

@BeforeEach
  void init() {
    closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classNotify, "EventType", "test-event");

  }
```

Comment: Have you tried this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
As it turns out the test class created awhile back by some previous developer was using Mockito and not Spring Boot Test. I had removed Extend With and replaced @Mock and @Spy annotations with @MockBean and @SpyBean so test became true Spring Boot Test. This solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Inside the `test method` need to add following code_

```
@Test
public void testIsValidFile() {

    AnyClass anyClass = new AnyClass();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(anyClass, "fieldName", "value");
    .........
    .........
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Spring Boot do a lot of automatically things to us but when we use the annotation `@SpringBootTest` we think that everything will be automatically solved by Spring boot.

There are a lot of documentation, but the minimal is to choose one **engine** (`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`) and indicate the class that will be used create the **context** to load the configuration (`resources/applicationl.properties`).

In a simple way you need the **engine** and the **context**:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyClassTest .class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String myProperty;

    @Test
    public void checkMyProperty(){
        Assert.assertNotNull(my.property);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you look the Spring Boot documentation you will find thousands os ways to do that.