# Resolve Spring @Value expression in JUnit tests

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4, spring-3

Here's a snippet of a Spring bean:

```
@Component
public class Bean {

    @Value("${bean.timeout:60}")
    private Integer timeout;

    // ...
}
```

Now I want to test this bean with a JUnit test. I'm therefore using the [SpringJUnit4ClassRunner](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) and the [ContextConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) annotation.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class BeanTest {

    @Autowired
    private Bean bean;

    // tests ...

    @Configuration
    public static class SpringConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public Bean bean() {
            return new Bean();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner can't resolve the `@Value` expression, even though a default value is supplied (a [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is thrown). It seems that the runner isn't even able to parse the expression.

Is something missing in my test?

Comment: This looks like similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353327/populating-spring-value-during-unit-test

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your test `@Configuration` class is missing an instance of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and that's why Spring does not know how to resolve those expressions; add a bean like the following to your `SpringConfiguration` class

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    ppc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    return ppc;
}
```

and move it to a separate class and use

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=SpringConfiguration.class)
```

to be more specific when running your test.

Comment: Works also without setting the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to ignore a not found resource.