# @Value config injection failing

Tags: spring, junit, code-injection

I am trying to run a spring JUnit test case using -
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:some.xml" })

The xml has bean defined along with in memory db details

```
<bean id="orderService" class="com.example.OrderServiceImpl">
        <!-- set properties, etc. -->
    </bean>
```

I am doing @Value injection inside the bean class OrderServiceImpl, but it does not happen while executing the test case but the same runs fine when I run the application. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer or PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to your test context. This SO question may give you a hint: [Populating Spring @Value during Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353327/populating-spring-value-during-unit-test).

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if a `some.xml` exists in both `main` and `test` trees. If it exists in both, the one in the `test` tree should override the one in the `main` branch.

Make sure the `some.xml` you are actually loading has a `property-placeholder`, such as

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:some.properties"/>
```

I realize that there are more modern ways to manage properties, but this is simple and easy to specify for unit tests.

I find that multiple tests become very awkward with config files on the classpath, so I like to take advantage of a feature of the `@ContextConfiguration` that lets me create a dedicated minimal config for each test.  The way it works is that for each test class, by convention, it can look for a config file in the same relative directory path as your test class package, and named after your test case.  That way you can completely control the config and properties for each test case. You might try it--it can eliminate confusion caused by shared config files.  To do it, remove the value in the`@ContextConfiguration`.  Then, say you have a test case `com.myCompany.SomeTest` located in `src/test/java/com/myCompany/`.  Create a file called `SomeTest-context.xml` in directory `src/test/resources/com/myCompany` and put the minimal config you need for that unit in the file. `@ContextConfiguration` will, by convention, find the config file of that name in that location and use it for your test. Although not part of the conventions I just spoke of, I put a properties file for each test in the same directory with just the properties I need for that test, named after the test case as well (e.g. `SomeTest.properties`).  In your test case-specific context, add a `property-placeholder` line like this to get your test-specific properties:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:com/myCompany/SomeTest.properties"/>
```

At the top of your test case, you would put

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration                        // no parameters
public class FileEncryptionUtilsTest { ...
```

If you do that, you'll be able to inject beans and values to your heart's content, without worrying about side-effects of things being added to a shared context or dealing with errors arising from multiple context files with the same name.

The key advantage is that you are testing a unit here, not the integration represented by an application context file. If you share an application context file in your unit tests, you're testing the application context along with your bean, and that's more of an integration test goal, not a unit test need.