# Cannot get value from properties using @Value in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I have a project template using spring and I need values from properties file, but when I run the program the value is null. Here is my code: 
Properties file contains: TOWN=Cluj

```java
    public class BaseTest {

           @Value("${TOWN}")
           public String stringValue;

           @BeforeTest
           public void beforeTest(){
               ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
               Student student =  context.getBean("studentBean", Student.class);
               student.displayName();
               student.displayTown();

               System.out.println(stringValue); // -> this is null
           }
       }
```

Beans file :

```xml
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

            <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:stable.properties"/>
            <context:component-scan base-package="com.base" />

            <bean name="studentBean" class="com.model.Student">
                <property name="name" value="MyName"/>
                <property name="town" value="${TOWN}"/>
            </bean>

        </beans>
```

```java
        public class Student {
            private String name;
            private String town;

            public String getName(){
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name){
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getTown() {
                return town;
            }

            public void setTown(String town) {
                this.town = town;
            }

            public void displayName(){
                System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            }

            public void displayTown(){
                System.out.println("Town: " + town);
            }

        }
```

In BaseTest when `displayTown(`) method is called the value from properties file works, but if a try to use the value as a variable in `BaseTest` the values is null.
Could you help me please ?

Comment: Is there any annotation on top of BaseTest like @Configuration etc ?

Comment: No this is the declaration of BaseTest 
public class BaseTest {

Comment: what is the base package of BaseTest Class

Comment: Spring doesn't inject values into arbitrary objects. Only into Spring beans. Your test isn't a Spring bean, so you can't expect Spring to inject anything in it.

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353327/populating-spring-value-during-unit-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have confirmed `BaseTest` is just a normal class. Values wont be injected automatically.

In xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:stable.properties"/>
```

It automatically configures `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, which replaces the `${}` placeholders, which are resolved against a specified properties file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.base" />
```

> Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be
>   auto-registered as Spring beans. By default, the Spring-provided
>   @Component, @Repository, @Service, @Controller, @RestController,
>   @ControllerAdvice, and @Configuration stereotypes    will be detected.

```
<bean name="studentBean" class="com.model.Student">
    <property name="name" value="MyName"/>
    <property name="town" value="${TOWN}"/>
</bean>
```

For `Student` class `name` and `town` fields will be automatically picked from property file

Please note this will happen only for `Student` class.

What you are trying is to get value in `BaseTest` class which is just a class.

Either Define a bean to inject property for `BaseTest` class like this

```
<bean name="baseTestBean" class="classpath.BaseTest">
    <property name="stringValue" value="${TOWN}"/>
</bean>
```

you wont need `@Value("${TOWN}")` in class

or

add any one configuration and it will automatically scan your class provided its under `com.base` package