# Maven test failing - Autowire of property not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot application and 'mvn test' is failing because Autowired is not working for reading value from application.yml file.

Class file:

```
@Configuration
public class LogConfig {

    private SettingsRepository settingsRepository;

    @Value("${build.version}")
    private String buildVersion;

    @Value("${build.name}")
    private String buildName;

    public LogConfig(SettingsRepository settingsRepository) {
        this.settingsRepository = settingsRepository;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void injectDataForLogging() throws SocketException {
        MDC.put("applicationToken", settingsRepository.getToken().isPresent() ? settingsRepository.getToken().get() : "NO-TOKEN");
        MDC.put("macAddressList", MACAddressUtil.getMACAddresses().toString());
        MDC.put("application", buildName);
        MDC.put("applicationVersion", buildVersion);
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
build:
  version: @project.version@
  name: @project.artifactId@
```

pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>something</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.version' in value "${build.version}"
```

When I run the application, everything works normally :/

Comment: There is no test class here. What is the test class that's failing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populating Spring @Value during Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353327/populating-spring-value-during-unit-test)

Comment: possible duplicate of :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353327/populating-spring-value-during-unit-test

Comment: Boot already provides this info for you in `BuildProperties`. (And why are you changing your MDC repeatedly when that info shouldn't change? And avoid `isPresent` whenever possible; instead, `getToken().orElse("NO-TOKEN")`.)

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider - the test class isn't the problem. It fails when loading the context while trying to execute tests. I have around 80 tests and all that are dependent on the context are failing.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- - I've corrected to use orElse(). Thanks.

I need to update the application token only since there is a scenario when you firts load the application (client-side) you don't have the token and you need to enter it. Once you save it, I need to update the MDC. 
I'll fix later how this works since it is still in the POC phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I went with using Spring's `Build Properties` bean.

Still not sure why this wasn't working but have no time to play with it anymore :D

Answer (score 0):

Just as you pass `pom.xml` properties to your `main` application.yml as it follows:

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

You will need to do the same to pass those properties to your `test` resources:

```
 <build>
    <testResources>
       <testResource>
          <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
          </testResource>
    </testResources>
 </build>
```