# How do constructor calls with the @Value annotation work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, javabeans

Hi I'm new to Java and Spring, and currently have a situation that is similar to this:

In Message.java

```
public class Message {
    final String text;
     
    public Message(@Value("${message.text}") String text) {
         this.text = text;
    }
}
```

In application.properties:

```
message.text = "This is some text."
```

Now, I have a test file where I want to write a test that checks the value of the String text, akin to something like

```
assertEquals(text, "This is some text.");
```

How would I go about doing this? It seems I can't manually invoke the constructor by doing `new Message("...")` because that overrides the @Value injection.

Comment: @Andreas The linked question was not a duplicate because it is discussing how to manage field injection; OP's question here is about context binding.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Too bad you removed it, because if you actually read answers [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41964308/5221149) and [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51810713/5221149), not just #1, then you'd see that this question was fully answered by them *(Answer: Use `@TestPropertySource`)*. Just because the OP of that answer chose to accept #1, doesn't mean that that's the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Value` annotation here is an instruction *to the Spring container*, so if you're wanting to test that it operates as expected, the only way to do that is to use `SpringRunner` or equivalent to actually start a context and feed it the value in question. Typically, this annotation isn't directly explicitly tested; rather, when the bean is covered as part of a medium-scale test like `@SpringBootTest`, its value will be set somewhere and is expected to be used in some business manner, the effect of which is tested.