# How to override a single application property in a test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

I have this test:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(AuthController.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
class AuthControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    AuthTokenFilter authTokenFilter;

    @MockBean
    AuthEntryPointJwt authEntryPointJwt;

    @MockBean
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @MockBean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @MockBean
    Authentication authentication;

    @MockBean
    SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Test
    void test1withEnabledTrue() {
    }

    @Test
    void test2WithEnabledTrue() {
    }

    @Test
    void cannotRegisterUserWhenRegistrationsAreDisabled() throws Exception {
        
        var userToSave = validUserEntity("username", "password");
        var savedUser = validUserEntity("username", "a1.b2.c3");

        when(userDetailsServiceImpl.post(userToSave)).thenReturn(savedUser);

        mvc.perform(post("/api/v1/auth/register/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(userToSave))).andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", is("registrations are disabled")));
    }

    private static UsersEntity validUserEntity(String username, String password) {
        return UsersEntity.builder().username(username).password(password).build();
    }

}
```

And this is the relevant part in Controller (Class Under Test):

```java
@Value("${app.enableRegistration}")
private Boolean enableRegistration;

private Boolean getEnableRegistration() {
    return this.enableRegistration;
}

@PostMapping("/register")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Map<String, String> post(@RequestBody UsersDTO usersDTO) {

    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    if (getEnableRegistration()) {
        [...]
        map.put("status", "ok - new user created");
        return map;
    }
    map.put("status", "registrations are disabled");
    return map;

}
```

I have this `application.properties` under `src/test/resources` and I need to override it, only for my single test named `cannotRegisterUserWhenRegistrationsAreDisabled`

```
app.enableRegistration=true
```

Probably I could use another file "application.properties" and another class test, but I'm looking for a smarter solution.

Comment: Tags do not belong in the title of questions, that is what the tagging system is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply configure the inline `properties` of `@TestPropertySource` which has a higher precedence than the properties loaded from `locations`/ `value` :

```java
@WebMvcTest(AuthController.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties" ,properties="app.enableRegistration=true" )
class AuthControllerTest {


}
```

All inline properties specified in the `properties` will override those specified in the `application.properties`

Comment: It works... But I needed to create another Controller. Is there something to change an application property at test level and not at class level?

Comment: it is still not possible with `@TestPropertySource`(see  [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18951))

Comment: why not just `@WebMvcTest(AuthController.class,,properties = {"app.enableRegistration=true"})` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `@TestProperty` annotation, which was an answer of a question on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41964308/6795321). However this only works on class level, not for one test only.

You probably need to make a new test class and add the tests where it the value needs to be `false`.