# How can i write unit test for ddmmYYYY validation with use java/spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, validation

```
    Accepting DateFormat : 01042021
```

1. List item

   ```
   Incorrect DateFormat : 9901042021 or 0104202199 etc.
   ```

   My date validation code blocks:

   ```
       @Value("${sms.date.format:ddMMyyyy}")
       private String DATE_FORMAT;

       public void validateDates(ReportRequest request){

           DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

           if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getStartDate())){
               try{
                   dateFormat.parse(request.getStartDate());
               }catch (Exception e){
                   throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid start date format, must be as : " +DATE_FORMAT);
               }
           } else {
               throw new InvalidInputException("Contract start date is empty");

           }

           if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getEndDate())){
               try{
                   dateFormat.parse(request.getEndDate());
               }catch (Exception e){
                   throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid end date format, must be as : " +DATE_FORMAT);
               }
           } else {
               throw new InvalidInputException("Contract end date is empty");

           }
       }
   ```

   My Unit Test:
   Getting error on first line because dateformat is null how can i fix it?

   ```
   @Value("${sms.date.format:ddMMyyyy}")
   private String DATE_FORMAT;

   public void testValidateDates() {


           DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
           ReportRequest reportRequest = new ReportRequest();
           ReportRequest.setStartDate("0104202199");
           ReportRequestValidator reportRequestValidator = new ReportRequestValidator();
           ReportRequestValidator.validateDates(reportRequest);
           assertEquals("Invalid start date format, must be as : ","0104202199");

       }
   ```

   How should I use the assert function, what should the condition be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populating Spring @Value during Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353327/populating-spring-value-during-unit-test)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `DATE_FORMAT` is not injected into your test class, so you get a NullPointerException.

Two way to solve it

1. use `@SpringBootTest`. Check this:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties
2. a more clean way: without any Spring annotation. This makes the test code much simpler. Just refactor your code:

```
// in your production code:
public class ReportRequestValidator {

  private String DATE_FORMAT;

  // package-private constructor for test 
  ReportRequestValidator (@Value("${sms.date.format:ddMMyyyy}") String dateFormat) {
     DATE_FORMAT = dateFormat;
  }

  // business logic...
 
}


// in your test code

@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedEx;

@Before
public void init() {
  expectedEx = ExpectedException.none();
}

@Test
public void testValidateDates() {
    String DATE_FORMAT = "PROVIDE_DATE_FORMAT_STRING_BY_YOURSELF";
    ReportRequest reportRequest = new ReportRequest();
    ReportRequest.setStartDate("0104202199");
    ReportRequestValidator reportRequestValidator = new ReportRequestValidator(DATE_FORMAT);    // inject DATE_FORMAT into validator

    ReportRequestValidator.validateDates(reportRequest);

    expectedEx.expect(InvalidInputException.class);
    expectedEx.expectMessage("Invalid start date format, must be as : 0104202199");
}
```