# How to mock the @ value using power mock not with Mockito?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, powermock

Need to set the `@Value` of the service class using `power mockito` not using Mockito.
Tried to set the value using `Reflection.utils(class , name , value)` it did not work , Since the class was using `PowerMockRunner.class`.

```java
    @Value("#'{test.codes}'")
    private List<String> testList;
    
    application-yml
    
    test:
      codes:005
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populating Spring @Value during Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353327/populating-spring-value-during-unit-test)

Comment: I tried all the options , This is the exisitng class , I need to use the same semantics such that PowerMockRunner.class and need to use the property file in ubnit test case.

Comment: You haven't shown us what you did, or told us what went wrong, so it is hard to offer any specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

With PowerMockito, using reflection I set values to filed before test execution.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    try {
        PowerMockito.field(ClassName.class, "fieldName").set(this, "fieldValue");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```